# Match consecutive vowels

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops, dictionary

I am trying to match capital cities that contain three consecutive vowels.

I tried this method with this code. It works if I don't have any commas.

```
pattern = r"\b(?=[a-z]*[aeiou]{3})[a-z]+\b"
result = re.findall, [pattern, capitals, re.I]
print(result)
```

But it doesn't work when I add the commas. I'm new to this. What am I doing wrong? I tried changing some things but still the same result.

This is the source:

```
capitals = ('Kabul', 'Tirana (Tirane)', 'Algiers', 'Andorra la Vella', 'Luanda', "Saint John's", 'Buenos Aires', 'Yerevan', 'Canberra', 'Vienna', 'Baku', 'Nassau', 'Manama', 'Dhaka', 'Bridgetown', 'Minsk', 'Brussels', 'Belmopan', 'Porto Novo', 'Thimphu', 'Sucre', 'Sarajevo', 'Gaborone', 'Brasilia', 'Bandar Seri Begawan', 'Sofia', 'Ouagadougou', 'Gitega', 'Phnom Penh', 'Yaounde', 'Ottawa', 'Praia', 'Bangui', "N'Djamena", 'Santiago', 'Beijing', 'Bogota', 'Moroni', 'Kinshasa', 'Brazzaville', 'San Jose', 'Yamoussoukro', 'Zagreb', 'Havana', 'Nicosia', 'Prague', 'Copenhagen', 'Djibouti', 'Roseau', 'Santo Domingo', 'Dili', 'Quito', 'Cairo', 'San Salvador', 'London', 'Malabo', 'Asmara', 'Tallinn', 'Mbabana', 'Addis Ababa', 'Palikir', 'Suva', 'Helsinki', 'Paris', 'Libreville', 'Banjul', 'Tbilisi', 'Berlin', 'Accra', 'Athens', "Saint George's", 'Guatemala City', 'Conakry', 'Bissau', 'Georgetown', 'Port au Prince', 'Tegucigalpa', 'Budapest', 'Reykjavik', 'New Delhi', 'Jakarta', 'Tehran', 'Baghdad', 'Dublin', 'Jerusalem', 'Rome', 'Kingston', 'Tokyo', 'Amman', 'Nur-Sultan', 'Nairobi', 'Tarawa Atoll', 'Pristina', 'Kuwait City', 'Bishkek', 'Vientiane', 'Riga', 'Beirut', 'Maseru', 'Monrovia', 'Tripoli', 'Vaduz', 'Vilnius', 'Luxembourg', 'Antananarivo', 'Lilongwe', 'Kuala Lumpur', 'Male', 'Bamako', 'Valletta', 'Majuro', 'Nouakchott', 'Port Louis', 'Mexico City', 'Chisinau', 'Monaco', 'Ulaanbaatar', 'Podgorica', 'Rabat', 'Maputo', 'Nay Pyi Taw', 'Windhoek', 'No official capital', 'Kathmandu', 'Amsterdam', 'Wellington', 'Managua', 'Niamey', 'Abuja', 'Pyongyang', 'Skopje', 'Belfast', 'Oslo', 'Muscat', 'Islamabad', 'Melekeok', 'Panama City', 'Port Moresby', 'Asuncion', 'Lima', 'Manila', 'Warsaw', 'Lisbon', 'Doha', 'Bucharest', 'Moscow', 'Kigali', 'Basseterre', 'Castries', 'Kingstown', 'Apia', 'San Marino', 'Sao Tome', 'Riyadh', 'Edinburgh', 'Dakar', 'Belgrade', 'Victoria', 'Freetown', 'Singapore', 'Bratislava', 'Ljubljana', 'Honiara', 'Mogadishu', 'Pretoria, Bloemfontein, Cape Town', 'Seoul', 'Juba', 'Madrid', 'Colombo', 'Khartoum', 'Paramaribo', 'Stockholm', 'Bern', 'Damascus', 'Taipei', 'Dushanbe', 'Dodoma', 'Bangkok', 'Lome', "Nuku'alofa", 'Port of Spain', 'Tunis', 'Ankara', 'Ashgabat', 'Funafuti', 'Kampala', 'Kiev', 'Abu Dhabi', 'London', 'Washington D.C.', 'Montevideo', 'Tashkent', 'Port Vila', 'Vatican City', 'Caracas', 'Hanoi', 'Cardiff', "Sana'a", 'Lusaka', 'Harare')
```

This is the output:

```
(<function findall at 0x10457cc10>, ['\\b(?=[a-z]*[aeiou]{3})[a-z]+\\b', ('Kabul', 'Tirana (Tirane)', 'Algiers', 'Andorra la Vella', 'Luanda', "Saint John's", 'Buenos Aires', 'Yerevan', 'Canberra', 'Vienna', 'Baku', 'Nassau', 'Manama', 'Dhaka', 'Bridgetown', 'Minsk', 'Brussels', 'Belmopan', 'Porto Novo', 'Thimphu', 'Sucre', 'Sarajevo', 'Gaborone', 'Brasilia', 'Bandar Seri Begawan', 'Sofia', 'Ouagadougou', 'Gitega', 'Phnom Penh', 'Yaounde', 'Ottawa', 'Praia', 'Bangui', "N'Djamena", 'Santiago', 'Beijing', 'Bogota', 'Moroni', 'Kinshasa', 'Brazzaville', 'San Jose', 'Yamoussoukro', 'Zagreb', 'Havana', 'Nicosia', 'Prague', 'Copenhagen', 'Djibouti', 'Roseau', 'Santo Domingo', 'Dili', 'Quito', 'Cairo', 'San Salvador', 'London', 'Malabo', 'Asmara', 'Tallinn', 'Mbabana', 'Addis Ababa', 'Palikir', 'Suva', 'Helsinki', 'Paris', 'Libreville', 'Banjul', 'Tbilisi', 'Berlin', 'Accra', 'Athens', "Saint George's", 'Guatemala City', 'Conakry', 'Bissau', 'Georgetown', 'Port au Prince', 'Tegucigalpa', 'Budapest', 'Reykjavik', 'New Delhi', 'Jakarta', 'Tehran', 'Baghdad', 'Dublin', 'Jerusalem', 'Rome', 'Kingston', 'Tokyo', 'Amman', 'Nur-Sultan', 'Nairobi', 'Tarawa Atoll', 'Pristina', 'Kuwait City', 'Bishkek', 'Vientiane', 'Riga', 'Beirut', 'Maseru', 'Monrovia', 'Tripoli', 'Vaduz', 'Vilnius', 'Luxembourg', 'Antananarivo', 'Lilongwe', 'Kuala Lumpur', 'Male', 'Bamako', 'Valletta', 'Majuro', 'Nouakchott', 'Port Louis', 'Mexico City', 'Chisinau', 'Monaco', 'Ulaanbaatar', 'Podgorica', 'Rabat', 'Maputo', 'Nay Pyi Taw', 'Windhoek', 'No official capital', 'Kathmandu', 'Amsterdam', 'Wellington', 'Managua', 'Niamey', 'Abuja', 'Pyongyang', 'Skopje', 'Belfast', 'Oslo', 'Muscat', 'Islamabad', 'Melekeok', 'Panama City', 'Port Moresby', 'Asuncion', 'Lima', 'Manila', 'Warsaw', 'Lisbon', 'Doha', 'Bucharest', 'Moscow', 'Kigali', 'Basseterre', 'Castries', 'Kingstown', 'Apia', 'San Marino', 'Sao Tome', 'Riyadh', 'Edinburgh', 'Dakar', 'Belgrade', 'Victoria', 'Freetown', 'Singapore', 'Bratislava', 'Ljubljana', 'Honiara', 'Mogadishu', 'Pretoria, Bloemfontein, Cape Town', 'Seoul', 'Juba', 'Madrid', 'Colombo', 'Khartoum', 'Paramaribo', 'Stockholm', 'Bern', 'Damascus', 'Taipei', 'Dushanbe', 'Dodoma', 'Bangkok', 'Lome', "Nuku'alofa", 'Port of Spain', 'Tunis', 'Ankara', 'Ashgabat', 'Funafuti', 'Kampala', 'Kiev', 'Abu Dhabi', 'London', 'Washington D.C.', 'Montevideo', 'Tashkent', 'Port Vila', 'Vatican City', 'Caracas', 'Hanoi', 'Cardiff', "Sana'a", 'Lusaka', 'Harare'), re.IGNORECASE])
```

This is my expected output:

```
ouagadougou
yaounde
praia
roseau
nouakchott
port louis
seoul
```

Comment: You call functions using `functionname(arguments)`, not `functionname, [arguments]`

Comment: The second argument to `re.findall` should be a string, not a list of strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately `re.findall()` wont work with this situation. The sample also has a tuple that can mess around when you iterate through the array. I think this is a better approach

```
result = [i for i in capitals if re.match(".*[aeiouAEIOU]{3}.*$", i)]
print(result)
```

EDIT:
So there is a way to use `.findall()`

```
pattern = r"[aeiouAEIOU]{3}"
three_consecutive_vowel_capitals = [c for c in capitals if re.findall(pattern, c)]
```

This will work too.

Answer (score 2):

`re.findall()` operates on a single string, not a sequence of strings. You can use a list comprehension to extract all the strings that match the regexp.

```
pattern = re.compile(r"[aeiou]{3}", re.I)
capitals = ('Kabul', 'Tirana (Tirane)', 'Algiers', 'Andorra la Vella', 'Luanda', "Saint John's", 'Buenos Aires', 'Yerevan', 'Canberra', 'Vienna', 'Baku', 'Nassau', 'Manama', 'Dhaka', 'Bridgetown', 'Minsk', 'Brussels', 'Belmopan', 'Porto Novo', 'Thimphu', 'Sucre', 'Sarajevo', 'Gaborone', 'Brasilia', 'Bandar Seri Begawan', 'Sofia', 'Ouagadougou', 'Gitega', 'Phnom Penh', 'Yaounde', 'Ottawa', 'Praia', 'Bangui', "N'Djamena", 'Santiago', 'Beijing', 'Bogota', 'Moroni', 'Kinshasa', 'Brazzaville', 'San Jose', 'Yamoussoukro', 'Zagreb', 'Havana', 'Nicosia', 'Prague', 'Copenhagen', 'Djibouti', 'Roseau', 'Santo Domingo', 'Dili', 'Quito', 'Cairo', 'San Salvador', 'London', 'Malabo', 'Asmara', 'Tallinn', 'Mbabana', 'Addis Ababa', 'Palikir', 'Suva', 'Helsinki', 'Paris', 'Libreville', 'Banjul', 'Tbilisi', 'Berlin', 'Accra', 'Athens', "Saint George's", 'Guatemala City', 'Conakry', 'Bissau', 'Georgetown', 'Port au Prince', 'Tegucigalpa', 'Budapest', 'Reykjavik', 'New Delhi', 'Jakarta', 'Tehran', 'Baghdad', 'Dublin', 'Jerusalem', 'Rome', 'Kingston', 'Tokyo', 'Amman', 'Nur-Sultan', 'Nairobi', 'Tarawa Atoll', 'Pristina', 'Kuwait City', 'Bishkek', 'Vientiane', 'Riga', 'Beirut', 'Maseru', 'Monrovia', 'Tripoli', 'Vaduz', 'Vilnius', 'Luxembourg', 'Antananarivo', 'Lilongwe', 'Kuala Lumpur', 'Male', 'Bamako', 'Valletta', 'Majuro', 'Nouakchott', 'Port Louis', 'Mexico City', 'Chisinau', 'Monaco', 'Ulaanbaatar', 'Podgorica', 'Rabat', 'Maputo', 'Nay Pyi Taw', 'Windhoek', 'No official capital', 'Kathmandu', 'Amsterdam', 'Wellington', 'Managua', 'Niamey', 'Abuja', 'Pyongyang', 'Skopje', 'Belfast', 'Oslo', 'Muscat', 'Islamabad', 'Melekeok', 'Panama City', 'Port Moresby', 'Asuncion', 'Lima', 'Manila', 'Warsaw', 'Lisbon', 'Doha', 'Bucharest', 'Moscow', 'Kigali', 'Basseterre', 'Castries', 'Kingstown', 'Apia', 'San Marino', 'Sao Tome', 'Riyadh', 'Edinburgh', 'Dakar', 'Belgrade', 'Victoria', 'Freetown', 'Singapore', 'Bratislava', 'Ljubljana', 'Honiara', 'Mogadishu', 'Pretoria, Bloemfontein, Cape Town', 'Seoul', 'Juba', 'Madrid', 'Colombo', 'Khartoum', 'Paramaribo', 'Stockholm', 'Bern', 'Damascus', 'Taipei', 'Dushanbe', 'Dodoma', 'Bangkok', 'Lome', "Nuku'alofa", 'Port of Spain', 'Tunis', 'Ankara', 'Ashgabat', 'Funafuti', 'Kampala', 'Kiev', 'Abu Dhabi', 'London', 'Washington D.C.', 'Montevideo', 'Tashkent', 'Port Vila', 'Vatican City', 'Caracas', 'Hanoi', 'Cardiff', "Sana'a", 'Lusaka', 'Harare')

result = [c for c in capitals if pattern.search(c)]
```

You don't need to use a lookaround when you're just testing whether a string matches a regexp rather than extracting the matching portion. Just use a regexp that matches 3 vowels.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
grep -i '[aeiou][aeiou][aeiou]' exatext1
#find lines which contain (words with) sequences of 3 consecutive vowels (it finds all lines with words like obviously, because of its three consecutive vowels).
```

Comment: This is a Python question, not shell.